# Gravity Forms Marketo Plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, feed, gravity-forms-plugin, marketo

I am wondering if anyone knows any hooks that I could use for the Marketo Gravity form Plugin?

Basically, I need to change the campaign Feed dynamically based on  a variable that will be in the URL (e.g. `http://URL.com?variable=feed`).

Currently, the way the plugin works is you create a marketo campaign in Marketo and then in WP > gravity forms > Marketo you assign a form to that campaign feed and then map the fields.

All I want to do is just change the feed based on the variable in the URL so it goes to its respective Marketo Campaign.

Ive tried contacting the plugin author and even a post in the support but to no avail.

Would appreciate any help.

Comment: Have you tried https://gravityplus.pro/gravity-forms-post-to-3rd-party/? At the very least, I'll work with you to get it working for your scenario.

Comment: Hi!, Thanks again for you reply. Where can I find this? I found the gravity+ stripe plugin.